# Finding the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to 2} \frac{x^3-8}{x-2}$ when naive substitution yields a division by 0

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to find the following.

> $$\lim\limits_{x\to 2} \frac{x^3-8}{x-2}$$

The book I am reading (Spivak's Calculus) provides the following answer:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 2} \frac{x^3-8}{x-2} = \lim\limits_{x\to 2} (x^2+2x+4)=12$$

I don't see how that works. Could you explain what is going on here?

Comment: Sorry, I had made my own typo. Does it work now? And if so, how?

Comment: Factor $x^3-8$ (hint: $x-2$ is a factor).

Comment: It uses long division of algebraic functions..thus $(x-2)\left(x^2+2x+4\right) = x^3-8$

Comment: Thanks. That makes a lot of sense now. If you see fit to write your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just divied $x^3-8$ by $x-2$ to get that
$$x^3-8=(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)$$

Comment: It's just the remarkable identity from high school: $\,\, a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$.